mixing different spring and spring boot versions
I have an application which uses spring boot 2.7.4. I want to replace some of the web components with newest spring boot 3.2.4, but I can't upgrade all of the dependencies right now. Am I able to upgrade some of the parts to the newest spring versions and keep rest with the old ones?
example config:
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.7.4'
  }
}

dependencies {

   implementation(
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.4',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc',
}


spring-boot 3.0.0 is very different from the 2.x , hence you d better upgrade them all to same version , differnent may cause potential conflict ,  resolve these is diffcult then upgrade spring version

Upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.4 to Spring Boot 3.2.4 involves a significant version jump, which may introduce more challenges compared to upgrading within the same major version. Pay close attention to any breaking changes.

Never mix modules from different versions (even minor ones!) of a framework, that will always lead to trouble. Upgrade everything or don't upgrade at all.

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not supported behavior by Spring Boot. However, that doesn't mean all hope is lost. You might be able to find alternative libraries that will add the features you want to your application and you can find time later to upgrade your application to Spring Boot 3.x. If you share the features you're wanting from Spring Boot 3.x, maybe we can give you some ideas of how you can implement the same thing in your Spring Boot 2.7.x application.
